# RxSwift using bindTo for binding Variable<String> to UILabel not working for Swift 3.0 update

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I use `RxSwift` to bind my `viewmodel` to `UILabel` and `UITexfield`. `UITextfield` ones have no issues converting to `Swift 3`, just replacing `rx_text` with `rx.text` worked.

But not for `UILabel`. On `Swift 2.2`, I used:

```
self.viewModel.shiftNameText.asObservable().bindTo(self.shiftLabel.rx_text).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

For `Swift 3`, I'm using `RxSwift` 3.0.0-beta.1 and tried just changing rx_text to **rx.text**, but it doesn't compile and shows this error "Cannot convert value of type '`AnyObserver<String?>' (aka 'AnyObserver<Optional<String>>') to expected argument type 'Variable<String>".`

Does anyone know why and how to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`UILabel`'s `rx.text` property is of type `AnyObserver<String?>`
so you need to map the value to an optional

```
self.viewModel.shiftNameText
    .asObservable()
    .map { text -> String? in 
        return Optional(text)
    }
    .bind(to:self.shiftLabel.rx.text)
    .disposed(by:self.disposeBag)
```

or in short:

```
self.viewModel.shiftNameText
  .asObservable()
  .map { $0 }
  .bind(to:self.shiftLabel.rx.text)
  .disposed(by:self.disposeBag)
```

See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/875 for other solutions.

Comment: Do you need to store the subscription in that case, or is the bind method smart enough to disconnect when the view is deleted?  It would seem crazy to know all that - the destination label, and still force you to book keep.  Thanks.

Comment: To answer my own question, from testing, it seems like it does unsubscribe itself and avoid a potential crash.

Comment: @ChrisConover If you delete the view by removing it from the superview and setting it to nil the subscription will still be active. Actually `bind` is equivalent to `subscribe` and returns a Disposable which is here added to a DisposeBag. When the view controller gets removed the DisposeBag cleans up the subscription. It does not crash, because the Observer is of type `Binder` which checks if the binded object is still available. See Binder.swift in RxCocoa.

Comment: You used to be able to bind for the lifetime of the receiving view, via rx.deallocated.  Do you know if this is still possible?  I looked for it, but find the documentation to be sparse.  Thanks - and for your earlier answer.

Comment: Oh yes, haven't thought about this. It is possible with `.takeUntil(shiftLabel.rx.deallocated)` in this case. When you add a `.debug()` to the subscribtion you can see that it gets disposed when the view was removed.